# Creating variables from list objects in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to create a binary set of variables that uses data across multiple columns.
I have a dataset where I'm trying to create a binary variable where any column with a specific name will be indexed for a certain value. I'll use iris as an example dataset.

Let's say I want to create a variable where any column with the string "Sepal" and any row in those columns with the values of 5.1, 3.0, and 4.7 will become "Class A" while values with 3.1, 5.0, and 5.4 will be "Class B". So let's look at the first few entries of iris

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

The first 3 rows should then be under "Class A" While rows 4-6 will be under "Class B". I tried writing this code to do that

```
mutate(iris, Class = if_else(
  vars(contains("Sepal")), any_vars(. %in% c(5.1,3.0, 4.7))), "Class A",
  ifelse(vars(contains("Sepal")), any_vars(. %in% c(3.1,    5.0,    5.4))), "Class B",NA)
```

and received the error

```
Error: `condition` must be a logical vector, not a `quosures/list` object
```

So I've realized I need `lapply` here, but I'm not even sure where to begin to write this because I'm not sure how to represent the entire part of selecting columns with "Sepal" in the name and also include the specific values in those rows as one list object to provide to `lapply`

This is clearly the wrong syntax

```
lapply(vars(contains("Sepal")), any_vars(. %in% c(5.1,3.0, 4.7)))
```

Examples using `case_when` will also be accepted as answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this using `dplyr`, you can use  `rowwise` with new `c_across` :

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Class = case_when(
      any(c_across(contains("Sepal")) %in% c(5.1,3.0, 4.7)) ~ 'Class A', 
      any(c_across(contains("Sepal")) %in% c(3.1,5.0,5.4)) ~ 'Class B')) %>%
  head


# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Class  
#         <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>   <chr>  
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa  Class A
#2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa  Class A
#3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa  Class A
#4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa  Class B
#5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa  Class B
#6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa  Class B
```

However, note that using `%in%` on numerical values is not accurate. If interested you may read [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)